# Dynamic Allocation of Arrays

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

I'm trying to write a simple flight reservation system for my school assignment. I should dynamically create an array without determining a size. Since I have to keep track of the size of the array, I declared an integer variable named as count in my class. I also have a flight class that has a copy constructor and a couple of getters. Then I wrote the following method

```
void ReservationSystem::addFlight(const int flightNo, const int rowNo, const int seatNo) {
    if (count == 0) {
        Flight *tmp = new Flight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo);
        listOfFlights = new Flight*[count+1];
        listOfFlights[count] = tmp;
        count++;
    } else {
        bool check = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < count && check; i++) {
            if (listOfFlights[i]->getFlightNo() == flightNo) {
                std::cout << "There is already a flight with that flight code" << std::endl;
                check = false;
            }
        }

        if (check) {
            Flight *tmp = new Flight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo);
            Flight** tmparr = new Flight*[count + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Flight *f = new Flight(*listOfFlights[i]);
                tmparr[i] = f;
            }

            tmparr[count + 1] = tmp;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                delete listOfFlights[i];
            }

            delete listOfFlights;
            listOfFlights = tmparr;
            count++;
        }


    }

}
```

I also have a `showFlight(const int flightCode)` method that shows the specific flight:

```
void ReservationSystem::showFlight(const int flightNo) {
    bool check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (listOfFlights[i]->getFlightNo() == flightNo) {
            std::cout << "Flight " << listOfFlights[i]->getFlightNo() << " has " << listOfFlights[i]->getAvailableSeats()  << " available seats" << std::endl;
            listOfFlights[i]->printSeats();
            check = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my default constructor and copy constructor for the `Flight` class:

```
Flight::Flight(const int flightNo, const int rowNo, const int seatNo) {
    flight = flightNo;
    row = rowNo;
    seat = seatNo;
    available = rowNo * seatNo;
    flightPlan = new char*[seatNo];

    // initialize the flight plan to all seats available
    for(int i = 0; i < seatNo; ++i) flightPlan[i] = new char[rowNo];

    for(int i = 0; i < seatNo; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < rowNo; ++j) flightPlan[i][j] = 'o';
    }
}

Flight::Flight(const Flight &obj) {
    const int flight = obj.flight;
    const int row = obj.row;
    const int available = obj.available;
    char** flightPlan = obj.flightPlan;

}
```

But in the line `if (listOfFlights[i]->getFlightNo() == flightNo)` xcode gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I think the reason behind this is a malfunction in my `addFlight()` method, because since there is no objects the array points to something null, right? And since it can't reach to `getFlightNo()` method, it throws this error.

Notice that this is my first time with C++, so I'm a complete n00b and I can be terribly mistaken. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That copy constructor looks really wrong, just setting a bunch of unused local variables.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::` container classes? Like `std::vector<>`?

Comment: If your school teaches you arrays and pointers and arrays of pointers that point to arrays and `new []`, and all this before `std::vector`, they are ripping you off.

Comment: There are many problems in this code. I perhaps could try and point them all out but would it do any good? There are probably more problems in the code you didn't post.

Comment: The assignment commands us to use only and only arrays that are allocated dynamically

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Your assignment is being written by someone who is unable/unwilling to teach the right thing.

Comment: Please refrain from "thank you" answers. Upvote all helpful answers, and accept the one most useful.

Answer (score 0):

What about `flightPlan` in `Flight`?

I see that is allocated in constructor

```
flightPlan = new char*[seatNo];
```

and that is copied in copy constructor

```
char** flightPlan = obj.flightPlan;
```

It's deleted in destructor?

If so, when you translate a `Flight` from the old array to the new array coping it (there are a lot of better ways to do it, but I'm looking for your error now)

```
        Flight** tmparr = new Flight*[count + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Flight *f = new Flight(*listOfFlights[i]);
            tmparr[i] = f;
        }

        // ...

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            delete listOfFlights[i];
        }
```

in new (copied) `Flight`s the pointers to `flightPlan` are pointing to a deleted area. Quite assured EXC_BAD_ACCESS when you use they.

p.s.: extra suggestion: avoid, when possible, the direct use of allocated memory; consider the use of a `std::vector<Fligth>` for `listOfFlights`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

```
            Flight *tmp = new Flight(flightNo, rowNo, seatNo); 
            Flight** tmparr = new Flight*[count + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // ****
            // **** You are trying to copy a flight. Why? You have an array of
            // **** Flight pointers. You need to make a room for one more poniter. 
            // **** You can continue pointing at the same flights as before.
            // **** You don't need an array of brand new flights.
            // ****
                Flight *f = new Flight(*listOfFlights[i]);  // <---- WRONG
                Flight *f = listOfFlights[i]; // <------------------ BETTER
                tmparr[i] = f;
            }

      // **** This is not needed any more
      // ****
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            delete listOfFlights[i];
        }
```

Problem 2:

```
            // ****
            // **** Learn to count. There are count+1 elements in your new array.
            // **** The first index is 0. The last index is count, not count+1.
            // **** You did get it right in the count==0 case.
            // **** 
            tmparr[count + 1] = tmp; //<--- WRONG
            tmparr[count] = tmp; // <------ RIGHT
```

Problem 3

```
// ****
// **** This copies nothing. It just creates and then forgets a bunch of local variables. 
// **** You probably don't need a copy constructor at all because 
// **** you don't need to copy flight any more.

Flight::Flight(const Flight &obj) {
    const int flight = obj.flight;
    const int row = obj.row;
    const int available = obj.available;
    char** flightPlan = obj.flightPlan;    
}

// **** Declare the copy constructor deleted instead.

Flight::Flight(const Flight &) = delete;

// **** If they are making you to use an old compiler that doesn't understand delete here
// **** Then do this instead:

private: Flight(const Flight &); // no implementation

// **** You may want to do the same with the assignment operator

// **** If you think do need a copy constructor for some reason, think again.

// **** OK, if you still think you need a copy constructor,
// **** make sure you DO NOT do this:

flightPlan = obj.flightPlan

// **** or an equivalent. You need a brand new copy of all of your arrays.
// **** Also maje sure to define a copy assignment operator.
// **** regardless, you need a destructor. Make sure you delete the arrays there.
```

Note, every single error here here could have been easily avoided by using `std::vector` instead of manually managed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for asking such a silly question. The problem is finally solved. Apparently, deleting the pointers you had just copied is bad and can cause problems in your code.

Thank you all for answering.